# error_log() after fastcgi_finish_request

Tags: php, fpm

What is the reason why [error_log()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) is not working after [fastcgi_finish_request()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fastcgi-finish-request.php)?

Also any error thrown by PHP is not written to the log.

setup: ubuntu18.04 + nginx 1.15.6 + php7.2-fpm, the error log is written to /var/log/nginx/error.log

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug, as stated in https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80628

It's expected behavior.

To solve the "problem", there are two options:

1. set PHP-FPM option "catch_workers_output" to "yes"
2. set php.ini option "error_log" to log file path (preferably)

Answer (score -2):

As stated in the documentation:

> This function flushes all response data to the client and **finishes the request**. This allows for time consuming tasks to be performed without leaving the connection to the client open.

So by finishing the request I assume no code after it will be executed like with `die()`

Comment: The HTTP request is finished and sent to the client, but the script execution continues, you can do db queries, curl requests, everything...

Comment: @the_nuts maybe you havnt set the error_log ini setting.